# Round datetime column to nearest hour in AWS redshift

Tags: sql, datetime, amazon-redshift

I have a table called orders which contains a column full of date timestamps

```
order_date
2021-04-15 15:48:32
2021-04-14 13:02:54
...etc
```

and I want to round them to the nearest hour in a new column, I can't find a function which does this. DATE_TRUNC('hour', datetime) always rounds down rather than to the nearest hour. Ideally the outcome would look like:

```
order_date             rounded_date
2021-04-15 15:48:32    2021-04-21 16:00:00
2021-04-14 13:02:54    2021-04-14 13:00:00
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The code is:

```
date_trunc('hour', order_date + interval '30 minute')
```